# Problem with simultaneously connection in game (NavyField Mobile)

Tags: google-account, google, accounts

I wonder if you can help me. There is a game called NavyField on the android system. The game allowed connecting two devices with the same Google account at the same time. You could play on one and chat on the other (online game) After the last game update (deliberately done by DEV) you can not connect two devices to game server at the same time. App cloning and similar things don't work.

My question is. Is there a way to get around this from the game client side?